# Codeigniter 4 not working with xampp with PHP 8.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, http-status-code-404

I have installed the latest version of xampp with PHP 8.0 and copied my current project (on Codeigniter 4 framework) which was running perfectly fine on xampp (PHP 7.4) in htdocs of xampp with 8.0. But it gives me error of 404, index.php on root and callback function on routes are working fine. but it can't access controller and gives 404.

any idea where iam wrong

Comment: You can try to check server logs

Comment: server logs are empty

Comment: Is it working with codeigniter development server? php spark serve ?

Comment: If you are on linux based system, you can have look at the file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter 4 comes with a local development server, leveraging PHP’s built-in web server with CodeIgniter routing.

You can start CodeIgniter development server on http://localhost:8080 by running `php spark serve`

Could you try this to check any issue on your CodeIgniter project file